# Is it possible to insert a new row at top of MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

All rows in MySQL tables are being inserted like this:

1
2
3

Is there any way how to insert new row at a top of table so that table looks like this?

3
2
1

Yes, yes, I know "order by" but let me explain the problem. I have a dating website and users can search profiles by sex, age, city, etc. There are more than 20 search criteria and it's not possible to create indexes for each possible combination. So, if I use "order by", the search usually ends with "using temporary, using filesort" and this causes a very high server load. If I remove "order by" oldest profiles are shown as first and users have to go to the last page to see the new profiles. That's very bad because first pages of search results always look the same and users have a feeling that there are no new profiles. That's why I asked this question. If it's not possible to insert last row at top of table, can you suggest anything else?

Comment: If you don't have billions of profiles you'd better using `ORDER BY` and an `INDEX` on _user_registered_date_: it's faster and solves all your problems. Inserting last profile on top (if you can do that) can make another query slow... so solving one problem and creating another one later...

Comment: an `order by` is a good to go. try read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382260/using-temporary-using-filesort-a-bad-idea-in-mysql maybe it give you some help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order in which the results are returned when there's no ORDER BY clause depends on the RDBM. In the case of MySQL, or at least most engines, if you don't explicitly specify the order it will be ascending, from oldest to new entries. Where the row is located "physically" doesn't matter. I'm not sure if all mysql engines work that way though. I.e., in PostgreSQL the "default" order shows the most recently updated rows first. This might be the way some of the MySQL engines work too.

Anyway, the point is - if you want the results ordered - always specify sort order, don't just depend on something default that seems to work. In you case you want something trivial - you want the users in descending order, so just use:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: This is not wrong, but he already stated he knew about ORDER BY, and he said this was too slow for his liking. Your answer should include a fix for the slowness (indexes, composite keys, explain select, ...)

Comment: Keeping a "default" order would necessarily mean some sort of time and memory consuming maintenance unless you never ever recover free space. It would also violate the SQL standard. I doubt such product exists.

Comment: Well, results can't be ordered the way he wants without a ORDER BY ... DESC clasuse. I don't see any other helpful information in the question, so I can propose indexes and stuff. I used an id in the simplest example, because that should be an indexed int column, and if you use this.. sort doesn't get much faster than that. If the OP provides more details I'd be happy to give more thought to the question :)

Comment: ORDER BY does not need to depend on "20 search criteria". It only needs to depend on 1 index, which is in your case is on ID. If you have separate index for ID, MySQL should use it. If MySQL can't use seperate index for ORDER BY, the only reliable way to order by reverse ID is to switch to a better DB or upgrade the hardware, and stil use ORDER BY.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to make sure that if you always need to show the latest data first, all of your indexes need to specify the date/time field first, and all of your queries order by that field first.

If ORDER BY is slowing everything down then you need to optimise your queries or your database structure, i would say.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add the id 'by hand', and give it a negative value, but i (and probably nobody) would recommend you to do that:

1. Regular insert, e.g.

   insert into t values (...);
2. Update with set, e.g.

   update t set id = -id where id = last_insert_id();

Comment: This would really not speed up the query.

Comment: What query are you talking about Konerak? of course that the `INSERT` will be made in 2 hits (will be slower), but regarding the `SELECT` he gets rid of the `ORDER BY` clause (faster) - this is what he wants (not what he needs)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you specify a auto_incrementing primary key.

However, you can just specify the primary key like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id signed integer primary key default 1, <<-- no auto_increment, but has a default value
  other fields .....
```

Now add a BEFORE INSERT trigger that changes the primary key.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_table1_each BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_id INTEGER;
  SELECT COALESCE(MIN(id), 0) -1 INTO new_id FROM table1;
  SET NEW.id = new_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now your id will start at -1 and run down from there.
The insert trigger will make sure no concurrency problems occur.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a lot of time has passed since the above question was asked.  But I have something to add to the comments:

I'm using MySQL version:  5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

When no **ORDER BY** clause is used with **SELECT** it is noticeable that records are displayed, regardless of the order in which they are added, in the table's Prime Key sequence.